# How to fix this unexpected error when using ionic and cordova

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

i am doing an online course which is ionic and cordova and encountered some error when trying to do anything with cordova.

My github repo is [Here](https://github.com/the-vv/coursera-ionic-and-cordova)

the error is below

```
C:\Users\The_vv\Documents\Ionic And Cordava\conFusion>ionic cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
> cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification --save
C:\Users\The_vv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:85
      } catch {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\The_vv\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\index.js:3:44)
[ERROR] An error occurred while running cordova plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification --save (exit
        code 1).
```

I dont know where this error comes from.
My Package dependencies is below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.16",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.9",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4",
    "typescript": "2.6.2"
  }
```

Comment: What version of Node are you using? Looks like v12 is required. https://github.com/ionic-team/native-run/issues/129

Comment: @BernardinoFrola okey thankyou bro, let me try that